# How should workflow time trigger be displayed at package xml file?

Tags: time-dependent-workflow, package.xml

I have a task to fulfill package.xml file with new developed workflow.
This workflow contains time trigger which send an email alert to recipient after some time of inactivity. As a metadata type, it's in the documentation described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm), but I couldn't find any mentions about how it should look in the package.xml file; seems like it shouldn't even be there...

Example from workflow file:

```
    <workflowTimeTriggers>
        <actions>
            <name>Some_name_of_alert</name>
            <type>Alert</type>
        </actions>
        <offsetFromField>Lead.CreatedDate</offsetFromField>
        <timeLength>24</timeLength>
        <workflowTimeTriggerUnit>Hours</workflowTimeTriggerUnit>
    </workflowTimeTriggers>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workflow metadata contains many sub-components:

- WorkflowAlert
- WorkflowFieldUpdate
- WorkflowKnowledgePublish
- WorkflowOutboundMessage
- WorkflowRule
- WorkflowTask

It's generally easier to deploy the `Workflow` metadata for the given object to make sure all dependent metadata is included rather than specify per each specific sub-component. Be aware this will deploy all related workflow metadata for that given object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>YourObjectName</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
<version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

If, for whatever reason, you did want to deploy pieces: you'll see that `WorkflowTimeTriggers` is within the `WorkflowRule` type. You didn't share your full workflow metadata file, but it's surrounded by `<rule>`

```
<rules>
    <fullName>RuleName</fullName>
    <actions>
        <name>ActionName</name>
        <type>FieldUpdate</type>
    </actions>
    <active>true</active>
    <criteriaItems>
        ...
    </criteriaItems>
    <triggerType>onCreateOrTriggeringUpdate</triggerType>
    <workflowTimeTriggers>
        <actions>
            <name>TimeTriggerFieldUpdateName</name>
            <type>FieldUpdate</type>
        </actions>
        <timeLength>30</timeLength>
        <workflowTimeTriggerUnit>Days</workflowTimeTriggerUnit>
    </workflowTimeTriggers>
</rules>
```

You can specify the rule by its name, but you also have to make sure to specify any related field update/email alert/outbound message/task used within the time based action separately. Below is an example of time-based trigger with a field update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>YourObject.RuleName</members>
        <name>WorkflowRule</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>YourObject.FieldUpdateName1</members>
        <members>YourObject.FieldUpdateName2</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
    <version>52.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Kris, I understand that we don't have this particular MD type and it shouldn't be separated from workflow or it's rule, because it's actually the option of some kind of process.